# The potential difference when neutral dielectric ($\varepsilon_r$) flows with speed $v$ through capacitor in magnetic field $B$

Tags: electromagnetism, polarization, dielectric

The distance between the two parallel plates of the initally discharged capacitor is $d$. Parallel to the plates there is a magnetic field $B$, as the image shows:

[image]

So we want to know the potential difference indicated on the voltimeter when an electrically neutral fluid of dielectric constant $\varepsilon_r$ flows with speed $v$ between the plates.

I started thinking about the case of a moving conducting bar in a magnetic field, and arrived at the wrong answear $U=Bvd$, which doesn't include $\varepsilon_r$.

I heard the solution has to do with dielectric polarization, what I don't really comprehend, so I don't know how to figure this problem out.